# SQL - Incorrect syntax error 'with'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

Hi can you please help me with this, Im using SQL Server 2005, im getting the "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'" error, Thanks

```
create table #Act(
iAId int, 
iPAID int, 
sResource nvarchar(10), 
sName nvarchar(50), 
W1 int, 
W2 int, 
W3 int)

    INSERT INTO #Act (iAId, iPAID, sResource, sName, W1, W2, W3)
        SELECT AC00000.iAId, AC00000.iPAID, AC00000.sResource, 
               Activities.sName, WK00000.W1, WK00000.W2, WK00000.W3
        FROM   AC00000 INNER JOIN
               Activities ON AC00000.iActTypeId = Activities.iActivityId INNER JOIN
               WK00000 ON AC00000.iAId = WK00000.iAId
    ;WITH acts (iAId, iPAID, sResource, sName, W1, W2, W3) AS
    (
         SELECT parent.iAId, 
                parent.iPAID,
                parent.sResource, 
                parent.sName, 
                parent.W1, 
                parent.W2, 
                parent.W3
         FROM   #Act parent
         WHERE iPAID is null

         union all

         SELECT child.iAId, 
                child.iPAID,
                child.sResource, 
                child.sName, 
                child.W1, 
                child.W2, 
                child.W3
         FROM   #Act child

        join acts
        on child.iPAID = acts.iAID
    )
    select * from acts
```

Comment: Should that semicolon (;) be there before the WITH...

Comment: @John K., yes 100% so. In any case `;`s are harmless as seen here `select 'hello';;;;;;;;;;;select 'world'` so it won't be the issue

Comment: what compatibility mode is your DB set to?

Comment: @Martin - I didn't bother asking that because SQL 2005 + Compat mode 80 **still** allows WITH

Comment: @ivzarate - IMO, there are only a few possibilities: 1. The query being executed is somehow different than what is posted. 2. The database in question is older than SQL Server 2005 or 3. The query is being executed through something other than SQL Server 2005+ Management Studio and that environment thinks its SQL Server 2000 (like say Query Analyzer as Richard mentioned).

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi - Ok. That leaves possibility 1 or 2. Odds on favorite IMO is 2: the database isn't SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WITH (Common table expressions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) only works in SQL Server 2005 or above.

Even at compatibility level 80, WITH statements work in SQL Server 2005.

- Check that you are not running SSMS 2005 against a SQL Server 2000 instance.
- Check that your server has only one instance of SQL Server, and it is the 2005 instance.
- run this to check

```
select @@version
```

---

Your exact error text comes up when you use "with" against SQL Server 2000

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.

Comment: The OP said he was using MSSQL 2005.